# Python: how to update GeoJSONDataSource?

Tags: python, bokeh, geopandas

Bokeh nowadays support `GeoJSONDataSource` that makes it much easier to work and plot data from `GeoDataFrame` as described [here](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L5/advanced-bokeh.html).

However I am not able to update. Let's suppose we have two shapefiles `shape1.shp` and `shape2.shp`. This what I am doing but I am not able to update the shape

```
import geopandas as gpd
from bokeh.plotting import save, figure
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox,layout, gridplot

f1  = gpd.read_file('shape1.shp')
f1g  = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=f1.to_json())

f2  = gpd.read_file('shape2.shp')
f2g  = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=f2.to_json())

select =  Select(title="Shape",  options = ['F1','F2'], value, ='F1')
geo_source1 = f1g ### first shape
p = figure(plot_width=600,plot_height=500)
p.patches('xs', 'ys', source = geo_source1, fill_color='white')

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    if select.value == 'F2':
        geo_source1.geojson = f1g.geojson   #first shape
    if select.value == 'F2':
        geo_source1.geojson = f2g.geojson   #second shape

select.on_change('value', update_plot)

controls = widgetbox(select1)
first_row = row(controls,p)
curdoc().add_root(first_row)
```